# SPImmediateAlertsJobDefinition errors in Event Log

Tags: timer-jobs, spweb

I am sporadically getting errors in my Event Log for SPImmediateAlertsJobDefinition with the ID 6893, I've seen some of the posts out there pointing towards issues with the SharePoint assembly files.  Yet I don't think this is the solution since this job runs but only fails say 25% of the time, this is a rough estimate but I do see it run.  In Event Log I see the entry for ID 6893, the source is SharePoint Foundation and it comes from the Timer Task Category.  Checking ULS I get:

*Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb.*

*The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPImmediateAlertsJobDefinition (ID 3b4f3122-46e4-4a9c-952c-a118758f3693) threw an exception. More information is included below.  Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb.*

*Exception stack trace:

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.DispatchTimerJob(Int32 lJobType, Guid gVServerId, Int32 lScope, Guid gDatabaseId, String bstrDSNServer, String bstrDSNDatabase, String bstrDSNUser, String bstrDSNPassword)

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPNativeDatabaseJobDefinition.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)*

Far as I know SPWeb should be set.  Has anyone found a solution to this or should I just ignore it expecting the next run to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, when doing upgrades, or [restoring from back ups](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942989), timer jobs aren't migrated correctly and [become corrupt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc561011%28office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: I saw that page and tried some of the solutions, but as I seem to need the Immediate Alerts job (and it only fails some of the time) I did not want to remove it.  Finally tried the Repair option, something I had been trying to avoid as I thought all machines in the farm needed it.  Sadly, none of this resolved the issue, the same Job still fails sporadically although, at least I know my assemblies are now up to date.

Comment: Accepting this as it seems to be the only lead although I'm still getting these in Production where we've never had restores so I don't think this is the only cause.